# Where can I download pfvar.h?

Tags: compiling, make, source-code

I'm trying to compile a source code and it needs this header file 'pfvar.h'

From where can I get it

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**UPDATE**]

You're trying to compile a source for the wrong architecture, I found pfvar.h in the [kFreeBSD headers for development](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/kfreebsd-kernel-headers). Basically you need a BSD-like system to build your program.

---

`net/pfvar.h` sounds like a kernel header, try to install the header files for your current kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: I downloaded many linux header versions and it's not included in any of them...I wonder if you can send it to me if you have it

Comment: pfvar is mentioned [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/pf.4freebsd.html), it's required to send ioctl to the packet filter pseudo-device. Again I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in the include paths. I'll look for it in the kernel git repo.

Comment: pfvar.h is available on freeBSD systems, visit: https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/kfreebsd-amd64/kfreebsd-kernel-headers/filelist

Comment: I downloaded Debian as a virtual machine, downloaded the header files and then sent the "pfvar.h" by email..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying from source? Usually when I have this kind of problem, it's because I don't have a -dev package installed for one of the dependencies. For example if XnetX was a dependency of a program I was trying to compile, I would need the XnetX-dev package installed from the software center. Doing this will download the source files for that package thereby allowing you to use the header and src files.

Comment: I'm using these source files for research http://nrg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mptcp/mptcp_userland_0.1.tar.gz and they say nothing about the dependencies

Comment: looks like it should be on your system already. Check out the /include/net directory. Also you could search for it with the locate command. "locate pfvar.h"

Comment: I searched the whole system and it's not there